# (PyTorch) TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, data-preprocessing, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to make a deep learning model for facial emotion recognition. I am using PyTorch to create, train, and test the model. I am using the FER2013 dataset as well ([https://www.kaggle.com/c/challenges-in-representation-learning-facial-expression-recognition-challenge](https://stackoverflow.com))

I have a python file called data_pl that handles the loading and preprocessing of data. In it are two functions, train_pl() and test_pl(). train_pl() handles the loading and preprocessing of training data while test_pl() does the same for testing data.

train_pl() works fine, but I keep getting this error with test_pl().

**This is my code:**

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms

#data_pl stands for data preprocessings & loading

#this is for data preprocessing and loading with train data
def train_pl():
    #the transformation we will apply to the images from the FER2013 dataset
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Grayscale(),
        transforms.ToTensor(), # Convert image to tensor
        transforms.Normalize(0.485, 0.229) # Normalize image
    ])

    # loading the data from the directory I have stored the downloaded FER2013 dataset
    train_data = torchvision.datasets.FER2013(root='/Users/raagulsundar/EmotionRecognition/data', split = 'train', transform=transform)
    print(f"Length of train data: {len(train_data)}")
    # create dataloaders so that the FER2013 data can be loaded into the model we will implement
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=19, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

    return train_loader

#this is for data preprocessing and loading with test data
def test_pl():
    #the transformation we will apply to the images from the FER2013 dataset
    transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Grayscale(),
        transforms.ToTensor(), # Convert image to tensor
        transforms.Normalize(0.485, 0.229) # Normalize image
    ])

    # loading the data from the directory I have stored the downloaded FER2013 dataset
    test_data = torchvision.datasets.FER2013(root='/Users/raagulsundar/EmotionRecognition/data', split = 'test' ,  transform=transform)
    print(f"Length of test data: {len(test_data)}")
    # create dataloaders so that the FER2013 data can be loaded into the model we will implement
    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=32, shuffle=False, num_workers=2) 

    return test_loader

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_loader = test_pl()

    for i, (images) in enumerate(test_loader):
        if images is None:
            print(f"Images batch at {i} is None.")
        else:
            print(images.shape)
    print('Finished loading data!')
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/EmotionRecognition/data_pl.py", line 44, in <module>
    for i, (images) in enumerate(test_loader):
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 633, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1345, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1371, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 644, in reraise
    raise exception
TypeError: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 308, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 54, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 265, in default_collate
    return collate(batch, collate_fn_map=default_collate_fn_map)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 142, in collate
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 142, in <listcomp>
    return [collate(samples, collate_fn_map=collate_fn_map) for samples in transposed]  # Backwards compatibility.
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/collate.py", line 150, in collate
    raise TypeError(default_collate_err_msg_format.format(elem_type))
TypeError: default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'NoneType'>

Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function _exit_function at 0x126552020>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/util.py", line 357, in _exit_function
    p.join()
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 149, in join
    res = self._popen.wait(timeout)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 43, in wait
    return self.poll(os.WNOHANG if timeout == 0.0 else 0)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 27, in poll
    pid, sts = os.waitpid(self.pid, flag)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/raagulsundar/anaconda3/envs/emotion_recognition/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/signal_handling.py", line 66, in handler
    _error_if_any_worker_fails()
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid 13295) is killed by signal: Terminated: 15.
```

I know it is happening on the `train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=19, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)` line, but I am not sure why.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I could fix it?

I tried seeing if it is an issue with the data path (it isn't). I tried to modifying the batch size because I saw somewhere else that someone made the batch size a factor of the length of the test data (still didn't work). Don't know what else I can do.